# Getting all possible pairs of numbers that have a difference of 1 in a list

Tags: python, combinations

I have a list `[0, 3, 2, 1]` and I want to find all possible combinations of 2 numbers that have a difference of 1, i.e. `|a - b| = 1`. So the desired result would be `[(0, 1), (3, 2), (2, 1)]`

I am aware of `itertools.combinations` and I know I can do it this way:

```
nums = [0, 3, 2, 1]
combs = list(combinations(nums, 2))
adj_combs = [comb for comb in combs if abs(comb[0] - comb[1]) == 1]
```

But it seems to be inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to do the same thing?

Comment: Just sort the list first.

Comment: Because I do not want combinations of numbers that are not adjacent to each other. Sorry for the confusion, by "adjacent", I don't mean the location in the list but their actual values (|a-b|=1).

Comment: `adjacent` is probably the wrong word — it means next to each other, `0` and `3` *are* adjacent to each other in your list.

Comment: "Adjacent" is usually used to mean next to each other in position, not in absolute difference.  Your question is confusing because of the way you phrased it.

Comment: What word would you recommend?

Comment: Is the order significant?

Comment: @MarkMeyer no, the order is not significant

Comment: If the order is not significant, you can `s = sorted(nums)` and then `[(m,n) for m,n in zip(s, s[1:]) if n - m == 1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you say order is not significant, you can simplify the problem greatly by sorting the numbers first.

```
>>> nums = [0, 3, 2, 1]
>>> sorted_nums = sorted(nums)
>>> adj_combs = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(sorted_nums,sorted_nums[1:]) if abs(a-b) == 1]
>>> adj_combs
[(0, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3)]
```